# VS Code on Mac stopped showing dart code metrics messages in problem panel

Tags: flutter, dart, metrics, analyzer, code-metrics

VS stopped analysing dart code metrics.

If I run it in terminal, it show all the metrics style problems.
(flutter pub run dart_code_metrics:metrics lib)

It worked before updating to Flutter 3.0.0.

[image: analysis_option.yaml]

Normally VS Code should mention a STYLE error. That there is a empty line needed before return statement.

[image]
[image: Flutter doctor -v]

Comment: I'm having the same problem since updating to Flutter 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute flutter upgrade!

With flutter version 3.0.1 its working well.